Launch Visual Studio Code server with Github Repositories extension and a github repository already open
Is it possible to launch Visual Studio Code server so that a particular github repository is open when a user first points their browser to the web UI? I need to use the Github Repositories extension to open the repository as a remote workspace.
This will require github credentials. I'd like to provide a github API token an environment variable (or in some other way that I can do on the backend, without the user needing to do anything in the UI).
Note that I do not want to "git clone" a repository locally, and I do not want to open visual studio code to a pre-existing directory. Rather, I want to make use of the Github Repositories virtual filesystem implementation to launch VS Code with a remote repository already open.
Note also that I'm not talking about using Github Codespaces here -- I want to run my own code-server. I'm also not talking about attaching to a remote container -- I'm running code-server locally, but I want to open a remote github repository as a workspace (i.e. the "Open Remote Repository" command in this extension)
